# Comparing algorithms for List intersection

Tags: python, algorithm

I am attempting to design an algorithm to find common elements between sorted and distinct arrays. I am using one of the following two methods. Is either one better in terms of runtime and time complexity?

Method 1:

```
# O(n^2) ?
common = []

def intersect(array1,array2):
    dict1 = {}
    for item in array1:
        dict1.update({item:0})
    for k,v in dict1.iteritems():
        if k in array2:
             common.append(k)          
    return common

print intersect(array1=[1,2,3,5], array2 = [5,6,7,8,9])
```

Method 2:

```
# probably O(n^2)
    common = []

def intersect(array1,array2):
    for item1 in array1:
        for item2 in array2:
            if (item1==item2): 
                common.append(item1)
    return common

print intersect(array1=[1,2,3,5], array2 = [5,6,7,8,9])
```

Comment: is there a reason you can't benchmark this code?

Comment: Have you compared them to the runtime of your using sets which support such operations natively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `array1` has `M` elements and `array2` has `N` elements. The first approach has time complexity `O(M lg N)`. The second approach has time complexity `O(M*N)`. So, from time complexity perspective, the first is better. Note, however, that the first approach has `O(M)` space complexity which the second one does not.

BTW, there is likely a `O(max(M, N))` algorithm.

Comment: +1. Two questions: 1) Second solution creates a new list and appends the common values, so it shouldn't be O(1) in terms of space complexity right?2) How did you get a clue that there was `O(max(M,N))` algorithm?

Comment: @ramailosathi: (1) The `common` array, the array that is returned, is present in both solutions. So, it cancels out in comparison. (2) I have an idea about the `O(max(M, N))` algorithm but since the question just wanted comparison between the two given approaches, I did not go into other approaches. Hint: think about the `merge` step in `mergesort`.

Answer (score 0):

`set(array1).intersection(set(array2))` will likely be the fastest solution. The `intersection` method is lightning fast and easy to implement. Not sure about its time complexity but you may want to take a look at its implementation.

Comment: you don't need the `set()` for `array2`. :)

Comment: Of course, native implementation is the best possible implementation.